# How do I filter out low occurrence nodes from a graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, gephi

I'm trying to make a graph using hashtags from [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram). Each node is a hashtag and has edges to each hashtag it was paired with in a post. I want to filter out the nodes (hashtags) with a low number of occurrences.

I'm able to filter them out by manually setting a limit like 35 or 30, but I want to make it so this limit is calculated using some parameters from the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how you want to adjust the limit according to which parameters of the graph.

Guess: you want to set the limit so that it eliminates some percentage of the nodes. e.g. you want to eliminate 10% of the nodes, those that have the lowest occurrence count.

- LOOP over every hashtag

  - Count occurences
  - save in array of pairs ( hashtag, #occurences )
- Sort pair array in ascending number of #occurences
- LOOP over sorted pair array

  - delete nodes with hashtag
  - IF required percentage of nodes have been deleted

    - STOP